# CSS box around box technique

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make an CSS division box with content in it as well as a border around it.

Instead of using the box-border technique, I was trying out a new box to box technique instead.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #outer{
    height: 20px; 
    width: 20px; 
background-color:#233D78; 


     }
     #inner{

height:18px; 
width: 18px; 
     background-color: #FFF; 

     font-size: 1em; 
     text-align:center;
     font-family:'Bookman Old Style', serif;
     padding: 0px; 
     margin-top: 1px; 
     margin-right:auto; 
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-bottom:1px; 
     vertical-align:middle;

      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer"><div id="inner">TEXT</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Somehow the borders are just not showing up right with FireFox.

I tried everything. Setting up the Paddings of both boxes, margin, and messing around with the width.

TO be honest, it took me around 30min to do this and I still can't get it right :(

I know that a way to achieve the same result would be setting up a border around just one box. But I just wanna learn this box around box background-color technique.

THanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What seems to work the most consistently is to use padding instead of margin.

```
#outer { 
   width:18px;
   height:18px;
   padding:1px;
   background-color:#233D78;
}
#inner {
   width:18px;
   height:18px;
   background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir.
This solves the problem in both IE and FF.

So you are suggesting that margin is no good in a technique like this? Or is it just inconsistent. 

Logically speaking, margin should work. Especially in FF which surprising is the browser that causes problems.

Comment: @webzide. I'm not sure why the top margin is not applied in FF (it has the same problem in webkit). Interestingly, if you apply `overflow:auto;` to the outer div, margin functions as expected (example: http://jsbin.com/ivofa4/edit). I would prefer to use padding anyway since I don't always want `overflow:auto`.

Answer (score 1):

You must know how the layout works! Using margin on the inner would work or padding on the outer would work.  Remember when applying margins, borders or padding to the element, they are layed out in that order. (The margin wraps the border, which wraps the padding,  which wraps the element.)

Below is using the inner margin create a box around a box border.

```
<html> 
<head> 
  <style type="text/css"> 
    #outer{ 
    height: 20px;  
    width: 20px;  
background-color:#233D78;  


     } 
     #inner{ 


     background-color: #FFF;  

    margin: 2px; 
      } 
  </style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="outer"><div id="inner">TEXT</div></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It works ok in IE allright but not in firefox

In firefox the top 2 "borders" are not showing up

Comment: strange firefox only likes the padding technique.

Answer (score 0):

Applying `border: 2px solid #fff;` on `#outer` solves the problem just fine. Then you can just get rid of `#inner`, since it's redundant.

BUT if you insist on using two DIVs, what you want to do is remove the `height` & `width` statements and apply `margin: 2px;` to `#inner`. This will allow 2 pixels of `#outer`'s `background-color` to be visible.